# Adding watermark into image won't work on the server but works perfectly on the local machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, watermark

I need some help on figuring out what are the reasons why? or what I've been missing on this because I could hardly figure out why this works in my local machine and is not working on the server. I have a code in C# to print a watermark on the image and it works perfectly on my local machine but when I applied it into my web host server where I'm updating my site. It won't print any markings. Any thoughts about this? Here's my code below to help you more track what might be the reason why it won't work from the server.

```
string watermarkText = "© mywebsite.com";

//Read the File into a Bitmap.
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file.InputStream, false))
{
    using (Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        //Set the Color of the Watermark text.
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

        //Set the Font and its size.
        Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("san-serif", 20, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        //Determine the size of the Watermark text.
        SizeF textSize = new SizeF();
        textSize = grp.MeasureString(watermarkText, font);

        //Position the text and draw it on the image.
        Point position = new Point((bmp.Width - ((int)textSize.Width + 10)), (bmp.Height - ((int)textSize.Height + 10)));
        grp.DrawString(watermarkText, font, brush, position);

        firstfname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName).ToString();
        newfname = ProdId + firstfname;

        bmp.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/"), newfname));
        con.Open();
        string sqlProductImagesTab = "INSERT INTO [ProdImagesTab]([ProductIdforImages],[ProductImages],[SellerEmail]) Values('" + ProdId + "','" + newfname.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + SellerEmail + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sqlProductImagesTab, con);
        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd3.Dispose();
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: What does it do instead? Does it show the unwatermarked image? Or does the method fail completely?

Comment: Yay for sql injection!

Comment: @Rob I'm trying to upload an image and want the uploaded images to be watermarked after being uploaded. The images are being uploaded perfectly but it doesn't show the watermark on it. So yes, I guess it only shows the unwatermarked image.

Comment: Does this code overwrite the original image? It's possible this method completely fails (highly likely because of the database connection), but fails silently.

Comment: @Rob I guess it overwrites the original image because everything works perfectly here in my local machine that's why I'm wondering.

Comment: Well, you should really know if it's overwriting the original image or placing it in a new location.. That's a crucial part of the workflow I'd imagine. Anyway, without seeing the rest of the code, it's hard to diagnose. As I mentioned, I think it's very likely your code is throwing an exception which is not visible, so the original file isn't replaced. You'd need to debug it a bit more, or add some logging within the method to see (if and when) it breaks

Comment: So sql injection? Do I need to watermark them first before it is being uploaded. With the database it only saves the filename,not the actual image.

Comment: It is not throwing any exception or something. I also checked the actual image file in my local folder and they are also being watermarked. So I guess the codes just works fine but it's not in the server.